# Separate visual styling for sessions in tmux

Tags: tmux

I wanted to set my status bar to be green in one session of tmux and red in another, but when I change it in one via command mode, the color status bar in the other session changes as well.

Is it possible to separate the visual styling of the status bars (or other) based on the session you're using?

Answer (score 0):

By using the man page and some trial-and-error I found that something like this works:

```
tmux set -t examplesession status-style "bg=red"
tmux set -t examplesession -a status-style "fg=black"
```

the `-a` is necessary in order to avoid tmux reverting all other style settings to defaults (in this case, losing the red background).